# HTML / CSS - Firefox Mobile - Issue With Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am having a scrolling issue with Firefox. I have a JavaScript game that responds to the user's browser size. The game works well with Chrome, etc... But with Firefox there is a scrolling issue.

My game is located here: http://beta.retandoclaro.com.mx/home/play/fr_game/flyingdog/

This game is meant to be played on a mobile phone. The problem is with Firefox, if the phone's screen is small, you have to scroll down to click "Play." When you click Play, it removes the div with the play buttons and shows the actual game. However, Firefox creates a problem where now there is a lot of scrolling because its trying to hide the address bar. The game automatically re-sizes to accommodate the width and height of the user's phone.

I am not really sure how to explain this, so I apologize if I am not making much sense.

I have tried to disable scrolling all together. However, none of these worked for this issue:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I want to disable scrolling, but I also need to make sure the Play buttons are visible. Is there some JavaScript I would have to write to subtract the height of the address bar from the body so that it all fits in the phone's screen without scrolling?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is this specifically about the mobile version of firefox only? If so, you should be specific about it. I'd edit the tags and title but I need to be sure that's what you intend. Also, it seems the `responsive-design` tag would also be releveant.

Comment: @ivy_lynx Yes, specifically about the mobile version of Firefox only. I took into account your suggestions and made the edits. Thanks